# Scaling textures across different objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, texture-coordinates

Is there a way to keep the checker texture the same size?

Currently it scales with the size of the object, even though the scale in the Cycles node itself is set to 5, a value of 5 looks different across the two models.

I'm pretty new to modeling so I might mess up on some terminology, but is there a node I could use -- that is universal between all objects -- that I can use to determine the size of the texture?

Or how would I make this texture consistent between the two models without manually scaling it down in the checker texture node?

[image]

Comment: Add Empty to a scene and use Texture Coordinates node with Object type (choose Empty).